# Why left padding does not work?

Tags: css, html, styles

I was expecting the following will place inner (red) square at position 50,50 in browser window coordinate frame. But it didn't. Why?

```
<body>
<div style="position: fixed; left: 0px; right: 0px; top: 0px; bottom: 0px; background-color: yellow; padding: 50px;">
    <div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; right: 0px; width: 64px; height: 64px; background-color: red">
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

**SORRY MY FAULT**

I was wishing to make "top:0px" for inner DIV but wrote "right:0px" instead. Just a mistake.

Comment: This is a rather.... peculiar.... way of doing things. Could you please tell us why are you using `position: fixed` and `position: absolute` in that way? There may be a better solution for what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Do you want the red square stays at that position upon scrolling? I wasn't sure what you meant by "browser window coordinate frame."

Comment: Please post and accept your own answer if you feel like you've solved this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`position: absolute;` takes your element out of the normal flow.  Since you specify it's left as 0, that's where it will be.

Comment: so why it doesn't do the same with top?

Answer (score 2):

your inner `div`'s position is `absolute`.  try `relative`, or not setting that attribute at all.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's because you `position: absolute` it to have `left: 0;` You likely want something like so:

```
<body>

    <div style="position: fixed; left: 0px; right: 0px; top: 0px; bottom: 0px; background-color: yellow; padding: 50px;">
        <div style="position: absolute; left: 50px; right: 0px; width: 64px; height: 64px; background-color: red">
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because of `position: absolute;` on the red square.

You can take it out and get [this](http://jsfiddle.net/jpnz9/), or set the `left` property and get [this](http://jsfiddle.net/PBKnv/).

Also, as a side note, some people suggest (myself included) to don't attach a measurement unit to a CSS property when the value is 0. Zero of something is still zero, so 0px, 0em, etc, doesn't matter, it always evaluates to 0.

Answer (score 0):

the left right top and bottom css means 'distance from'.  It's not meant to be used the way you are using it.

Here's a better example: http://jsfiddle.net/xAuLJ/

```
<body>
<div style="position: fixed; width:100%; height:100%; background-color: yellow;">
    <div style="position: absolute; left: 50%; top: 50%; width: 64px; height: 64px; margin-top:-32px; margin-left:-32px; background-color: red">
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

It was my own fault. I was wishing to make "top:0px" for inner DIV but wrote "right:0px" instead. When element moved down but not right I decided top padding processed differently than left.

Comment: Probably best to incorporate this into your question rather than creating a new answer.